# Specific external IP not reachable

Tags: ubuntu, ip, routing, systemd-networkd, netplan

I have an ubuntu machine(22.04 LTS) with multiple network interfaces and firewall disabled.

When I ping /traceroute any external IP address it works as expected, with a single exception: `178.x.x.x`.
If I ping this IP from any other machine it's working fine, but from this install base it simply timeout.

I tried to look into ip routes/netplan config but I can't figure it out.

`ip r`:

```
default           via  51.x.x.254    dev    eno1    proto  dhcp  src  51.x.x.57    metric  100
51.x.x.0/24       dev  eno1          proto  kernel  scope  link  src  51.x.x.57    metric  100
51.x.x.254        dev  eno1          proto  dhcp    scope  link  src  51.x.x.57    metric  100
192.168.169.0/24  dev  eno2          proto  kernel  scope  link  src  192.168.169.3
213.x.x.99        via  51.x.x.254    dev    eno1    proto  dhcp  src  51.x.x.57    metric  100
```

and `ip rule list`

```
0:      from  all  lookup  local
32766:  from  all  lookup  main
32767:  from  all  lookup  default
```

and finally `traceroute 178.x.x.x`:

```
traceroute to 178.x.x.x (178.x.x.x), 64 hops max
  1   51.x.x.252  0.529ms  0.408ms  0.383ms
  2   *  *  *
  3   *  *  *
  4   *  *  *
  5   *  *  *
```

This is driving me crazy as I cannot figure out what's wrong and why that IP it's not reachable on this exact machine(from others it works just fine).

`netplan get all` returns:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        lo:
            dhcp4: false
            optional: true
            addresses:
            - 127.0.0.1/8
        eno1:
            accept-ra: false
            addresses:
            - 51.x.x.57/24
            dhcp4: false
            match:
                macaddress: x:x:x:x:x:x
            set-name: eno1
        eno2:
            match:
                macaddress: x:x:x:x:x:x
            addresses:
            - 192.168.169.3/24
            dhcp4: false
            set-name: eno2
            routes:
            -   to: default
                via: 255.255.255.0
                on-link: true
```

Edit:

There are 3 machines(full ssh access to everything), all of them are using the same gateway `51.x.x.254`, the address `178.x.x.x` it's on one of them. The `178.x.x.x` it's accessible from outside but not from one of the machines(the one that I have issues with).
If I traceroute anything else besides the IP in question it works as expected.

Edit 2:

The firewall it's disabled on all 3 machines. The `178.x.x.x` address it's configured on first machine as:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      optional: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
      addresses:
      - "178.x.x.x/29"
      - "51.x.x.55/24"
      dhcp4: false
      set-name: "eno1"
    eno2:
      addresses:
      - "192.168.169.1/24"
      dhcp4: false
```

`ip -br link; ip -4 -br addr; ip -4 rule; ip -4 neigh ; ip -4 route` from first machine:

```
lo               UNKNOWN         <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
enx8ac862b39a5b  DOWN            <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
eno1             UP              <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
eno2             UP              <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
eno1             UP             178.x.x.x/29 51.x.x.55/24 metric 100
eno2             UP             192.168.169.1/24
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
51.x.x.254 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
192.168.169.6 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
192.168.169.3 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
192.168.169.5 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
192.168.169.4 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
192.168.169.2 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.57 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.56 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.253 dev eno1 lladdr  STALE
51.x.x.252 dev eno1 lladdr  STALE
default via 51.x.x.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 51.x.x.55 metric 100
51.x.x.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 51.x.x.55 metric 100
51.x.x.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 51.x.x.55 metric 100
178.x.x.x/29 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 178.x.x.x
192.168.169.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.169.1
213.x.x.99 via 51.x.x.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 51.x.x.55 metric 100
```

The second machine which can access `178.x.x.x` it's configured as:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - "51.x.x.56/24"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
      dhcp4: false
      set-name: "eno1"
    eno2:
      addresses:
      - "192.168.169.2/24"
      dhcp4: false
```

`ip -br link; ip -4 -br addr; ip -4 rule; ip -4 neigh ; ip -4 route` from second machine

```
lo               UNKNOWN         <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
enx7e6c479cb2e0  DOWN            <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
eno1             UP              <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
eno2             UP              <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
eno1             UP             51.x.x.56/24
eno2             UP             192.168.169.2/24
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
192.168.169.3 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
192.168.169.1 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.56 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.57 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.252 dev eno1 lladdr  STALE
51.x.x.253 dev eno1 lladdr  STALE
51.x.x.254 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
default via 51.x.x.254 dev eno1 proto static onlink
51.x.x.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 51.x.x.56
192.168.169.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.169.2
```

`ip -br link; ip -4 -br addr; ip -4 rule; ip -4 neigh ; ip -4 route` from third machine(the one that cannot reach `178.x.x.x`):

```
lo               UNKNOWN         <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP>
enx7e6c479cb2e0  DOWN            <BROADCAST,MULTICAST>
eno1             UP              <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
eno2             UP              <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8
eno1             UP             51.x.x.57/24
eno2             UP             192.168.169.3/24
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
192.168.169.2 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
192.168.169.1 dev eno2 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.56 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.55 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
51.x.x.252 dev eno1 lladdr  STALE
51.x.x.253 dev eno1 lladdr  STALE
51.x.x.254 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE
default via 51.x.x.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 51.x.x.57 metric 100
51.x.x.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 51.x.x.57 metric 100
51.x.x.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp scope link src 51.x.x.57 metric 100
192.168.169.0/24 dev eno2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.169.3
213.x.x.99 via 51.x.x.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp src 51.x.x.57 metric 100
```

`nft list ruleset` also empty on all 3 machines

Comment: so if you traceroute anything else, what doe the first 2 or 3 lines in the output show? is it ALL 178.x.x.x or a specific one? (no, I don't want you to reveal which one if it is specific)

Comment: When you say *"this exact machine(from others it works just fine)"*, you mean are *all* connected to the same network? Or, in the same vein, the problem in that machine happens on any network connection?

Comment: You seem to be focused on pings. Is there a reason for that? What about other protocols? Your traceroute output clearly shows that UDP frames to 178.x.x.x go out of your machine and reach your gateway. What is filtering out ping requests or replies is probably external to your machine.

Comment: Try `traceroute -I 178.x.x.x` (traceroute with ICMP ECHO) to confirm ICMP frames are not filtered out by your machine. Or `ping -t 1 178.x.x.x` if your traceroute does not have a `-I` option.

Comment: `If I ping this IP from any other machine it's working fine` Do the other machines use the same default gateway (51.x.x.254)? And who manages it?

Comment: @JaromandaX If I trace anything else it works as expected

Comment: thanks, you didn't answer either of my questions - is it any address that starts with `178.` or a specific one? or a specific subnet that starts with `178.`

Comment: @TomYan There are 3 machines all of them are using the same gateway, on the other 2 everything works as expected (the `178.x.x.x` ip it's mounted on one of them and it's accessible from outside). I have full ssh access to all three machines

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a specific one that doesn't work

Comment: `the 178.x.x.x ip it's mounted on one of them` what do you mean by "mounted on" ... do you mean one of the other machines has that IP address?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, one of the other machines has this IP address

Comment: and this machine is *external* or internal? i.e is it on the other side of your default gateway, or on the same side as the machine that can't reach it?

Comment: question: "I have an ubuntu machine(22.04 LTS) " . comment "There are 3 machines all of them are using the same gateway" "I have full ssh access to all three machines" . It's really time you update your question with relevant information rather than having multiple persons attempt to pull the information and get answers drop by drop.

Comment: It took 11 comments to tell that 178.x.x.x belongs to one additional system you own and is "near" others systems. Why wasn't this piece of information in the question in the first place? You'll have to provide the configurations of all of these systems Or at least 3 of them: the one with 178, the one which can reach it and the one which can't reach it. Same kind of information: addresses, routes, firewalls, special setup (non exhaustive example: Docker in itself is a special setup) etc. I'm sure I forget something, but *you* shouldn't forget it.

Comment: Now it looks like the problem is in the category of "a multi-homed routing problem", but without all the little tiny details the answer will be: fix the routing problems caused by being multi-homed. These should be enough for the little tiny details: `ip -br link; ip -4 -br addr; ip -4 rule; ip -4 neigh ; ip -4 route` + `nft list ruleset`. For the 3 systems + a system for which it works (the system matching "If I ping this IP from any other machine it's working fine").

Comment: Obfuscation doesn't help. host2 has the address `51.x.x.56/24` on eno1 and at the same time has an ARP entry `51.x.x.56 dev eno1 lladdr  REACHABLE`. Either a typo or a same-address conflict within the LAN which would be bad. As it's about hunting for the little detail, some of them obfuscated (eg: MAC addresses would have helped figuring this out), details should better be correct or clarified including this one. Then why obfuscate the last part of 178.../29 ? I'll assume 2nd (not 1st) address of a block (eg .1/29 ,  .9/29 or .17/29 etc...)

Comment: Anyway I made a model of the whole setup and everything can reach everything, with the router sending ICMP redirects to host2 and to host3 (eg after having replaced missing values: `From 51.1.1.254: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 178.2.2.9)` ) since everything is in the same LAN. If your host provider's router has a different configuration, or if one of the hosts doesn't behave the same with ICMP redirect etc. etc. then things could differ. Can't go further than what I tried. I would still expect additional problems with UDP services on host1 because UDP and multi-homing requires more.